# Python Find text at end of html element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, find

I need to pull the movie title and year out of the HTML text below using the BeautifulSoup find() method.

the below returns the name of the movie, but I'm unable to return only the year

find('p').find('a').text

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
<div class="poster-container">
<a class="poster-link" href="/title/80244680/">
<img alt="A Tale of Two Kitchens (2019)" class="poster" src="https://occ-0-37-33.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/0DW6CdE4gYtYx8iy3aj8gs9WtXE/AAAABfTGUtIG2HYlEhUbvzPHmiAyPSkDcBIhQx_Ey06KfkgaUEwELBtJsJYP71-Vsx06NTKFKWZQupZGNVE8DCo8dC0j-zpcaNCPGFiyNJKN7tonZ3gMSAM.jpg?r=397"/>
<div class="overlay d-none d-lg-block text-center">
<span class="d-block font-weight-bold small mt-3">Documentaries</span>
<span class="d-block font-weight-bold small">International Movies</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<p><strong><a href="/title/80244680/">A Tale of Two Kitchens</a></strong><br/>2019</p>
</div>
A Tale of Two Kitchens
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_element.contents[-1]
```

This will give you the last element contained inside `my_element`: in this case, if `my_element` is the `<p>`, this will give the text "2019" as a `NavigableString`. (The *first* child is the `<strong>` tag, which contains `<a>` and all the rest.)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.find the `<a>` tag and then use `next_element`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
<div class="poster-container">
<a class="poster-link" href="/title/80244680/">
<img alt="A Tale of Two Kitchens (2019)" class="poster" src="https://occ-0-37-33.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/0DW6CdE4gYtYx8iy3aj8gs9WtXE/AAAABfTGUtIG2HYlEhUbvzPHmiAyPSkDcBIhQx_Ey06KfkgaUEwELBtJsJYP71-Vsx06NTKFKWZQupZGNVE8DCo8dC0j-zpcaNCPGFiyNJKN7tonZ3gMSAM.jpg?r=397"/>
<div class="overlay d-none d-lg-block text-center">
<span class="d-block font-weight-bold small mt-3">Documentaries</span>
<span class="d-block font-weight-bold small">International Movies</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<p><strong><a href="/title/80244680/">A Tale of Two Kitchens</a></strong><br/>2019</p>
</div>
A Tale of Two Kitchens
<br/>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

item=soup.select_one('.col-sm-6.col-lg-3').find_next('p')
print(item.text)
```

Output:

> A Tale of Two Kitchens2019

---

```
item=soup.select_one('.col-sm-6.col-lg-3').find_next('p').find('a').text
print(item)
```

output:

> A Tale of Two Kitchens

---

```
item=soup.select_one('.col-sm-6.col-lg-3').find_next('p').find('a').next_element.next_element.next_element
print(item)
```

output:

> 2019

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful as well. The output you provided though isn't indented so I can't read it, but the functions you provided are helpful nonetheless!